# Add background Image on widget Text using PIL

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I would like to know if there is a command that will put the image in the foreground, set it to transparent and block it, that is, the picture will look like a background for a text editor

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. You can't use a picture for the background of a text widget.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh